# What are -webkit-paged-y and -webkit-paged-x values for overflow

Tags: css

I've looked around SO but the questions I've found having anything to do with `overflow: -webkit-paged-y` or `overflow: -webkit-paged-x` don't explain what they are or do. Presumably, these prefixes would just be additions for `paged-x` or `y` but there is no `overflow` property value named so. On Chrome and Safari, those values seem to add a height (auto) for the entire container making everything fit without any fuss.

I used these on a deeply nested markup and it worked, but I have no clue what those values are or why they worked. Information on them is scarce as well.

Comment: These values are part of paged module, they have significance when you use @page, some details are here https://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto2.12/paged-overflow/ and https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-css-overflow-3-20130418/

Comment: not sure if this will become a standard

Comment: Very interesting, looks like documentation for paged is missing from the updated docs though. Could be a hint that it won't become standard.

Comment: Yes, lot of back and forth conversations are there in the draft

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"*These are old webkit-specific properties that allowed developers to fragment content over columns inside a scrollable region*" [1]

Chromium (Chrome 75, June 2019) removed support for
`overflow: -webkit-paged-x` and `-webkit-paged-y`.
Currently it is still supported by WebKit/Safari.

See
[1] https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5731653806718976
and https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/m/#!topic/blink-dev/_UhJEz04sqA

These links include an example for the intended use and how to do the same with `overflow-x:scroll` and `column-width`